# How to send array request in body parameter retrofit android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, okhttp

This is my Request which i need to send in @Post request with **Data** as a key. Please help me, I am stuck since 2 days.

```
[
    {
        "barcodeList": "abc",
        "fieldboyId": "17",
        "lattitude": "37.4219513",
        "longitude": "-122.0841169",
        "quantity": "2",
        "refrenceId": "1",
        "sampleId": null,
        "sampleName": null,
        "sampleType": null,
        "type": "Barcode"
    },
    {
        "barcodeList": "acd",
        "fieldboyId": "17",
        "lattitude": "37.4219513",
        "longitude": "-122.0841169",
        "quantity": "1",
        "refrenceId": "1",
        "sampleId": null,
        "sampleName": null,
        "sampleType": null,
        "type": "Barcode"
    }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score -1):

You could make these classes:

```
public class RequestBody {
    List<Data> data;

    public class Data {
        String barcodeList;
        String fieldboyId;
        String lattitude;
        String longitude;
        String quantity;
        String refrenceId;
        String sampleId;
        String sampleName;
        String sampleType;
        String type;
    }
}
```

and in the interface something like

```
@POST("/api/path")
Call<Something> myPostRequest(@Body requestBody: RequestBody);
```

Comment: Can you pls help in java ???

Comment: I apologise, sorry, I missed that it wasn't a kotlin question. It's been a long time since I did it in Java. I will try to edit my answer

Comment: Waiting for your help.